# Direct and Indirect bandgap

Tags: bandgap

How can I know which one is direct bandgap material and which one is indirect?

Why does Germanium have an indirect bandgap? How can be it become a direct bandgap material?

Here, I have attached a picture where I have calculated the direct and indirect bandgap of Germamium.

I increased its pressure by reducing the cellsize.

Is there any way of understanding, which one has a direct bandgap and which one has an indirect band gap?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to determine whether a material has direct band gap without actually doing a calculation, or how to determine whether a material has direct band gap from calculation results?

Answer (score 6):

In order to know if your material has direct/indirect band gap, you need to calculate the electronic band structure: Energy vs **k**.

Then, you look for the smaller $\Delta E$ between the bottom of the conduction band (BCB) and the top of the valence band (TVB). If this $\Delta E$ occurs for the same value of **k**, then you have a direct band gap material, otherwise, you will have an indirect band gap material.

The image bellow correspond to the Germanium<sup>[1](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/Ge/bandstr.html)</sup>. As you can see, the smaller $\Delta E$ occurs between the BCB at  **k** = $\langle 111 \rangle$ ($L$ point) and TVB at **k** $= \langle 000 \rangle$ ($\Gamma$ point).

[image]

About ***Why?***, I recommend to watch the Richard Feynman interview about magnets [here](https://youtu.be/36GT2zI8lVA).